# Finding values of k when f(x) is continuous at x=0

Tags: calculus

Find all values of $k$ such that given function

$$
f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
  \frac{\sin x}{x}, & \text{ if } x \not= 0 \\
  k, & \text{ if } x = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$

is continuous at $x = 0$.

Comment: Do you know what you need in order for $f$ to be continuous in $0$?

Comment: Lim 0+ = Lim 0- ?

Comment: @T.f7 Indeed so, so that the limit exists...and equals the value of the function at that point! This answers your question under my answer, too.

Answer (score 3):

$$\text{We know}\;\;\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$$

Comment: I know this part, but what about the other part? ( k, when x =0)

Comment: @T.f7 Then use the [definition of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_functions) at $x=0$.